# Angular 10 Upgrade - Fix CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts

Tags: javascript, angular, angular10, angular-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my Angular 9 app to Angular 10 version, but getting below warning after the upgrade

```
WARNING in calendar.reducer.ts depends on lodash/keys. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
```

I have added below line to my `angular.json` file but issue is not resolved

```
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["lodash"]
```

How can I fix above issue.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the linked question. It has been asked and answered earlier. Additionally, the other question is about RxJS, this question is about lodash. They are similar, but not duplicate. Please re-open.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

The npm package `lodash` itself is not an ECMAScript module and therefore produces the warning. As a result, you may have a significantly increased bundle size, as the compiler is not able to perform [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).
Here is how you can get rid of the warning:

### Replace with ES modulized library (recommended)

Some libraries offer ES modulized builds. In case of `lodash`, you can replace it with [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es).

Run `npm install --save lodash-es`.

Now replace all imports from `lodash` with `lodash-es`. Also make sure to import the library with ES import statements:

```js
import { keys } from 'lodash-es';
```

This will ensure that the compiler can optimize out unused symbols from the package.

### Whitelist CommonJS dependency

If there is no ES modulized build available for your library, or if you for some reason don't care, you can allow specific CommonJS dependencies in the `angular.json` file (this may significantly increase the bundle size of your application):

```json
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["lodash"]
    }
  }
}
```

> Since Angular CLI Version 10.0.1 you can use globs in `allowedCommonJsDependencies`.
> This means that if you pass `lodash`, the sub-paths (e.g. `lodash/keys`) will also be allowed.

Docs reference: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Comment: Tried it but issue still exist

Comment: Imported like this - import keys from 'lodash/keys'

Comment: Getting error like cannot find module 'lodash-es', do I need to npm install 'lodash-es' ?

Comment: yes you need to install `lodash-es`. I'm updating my answer to make it more clear

Comment: `Property allowedCommonJsDependencies is not allowed.`

Comment: @Cleancode did you put it to the right place? (`architect` - `build` - `options`) Updated my answer, now it should be more clear where to put it.

Comment: Yes, I did and it was working before. Just cleaned the `npm cache` and let me try reinstalling the packages

Comment: Here is a packaged version of lodash-es : https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es. Now you can build it yourself with lodash CLI.

Comment: @Basheer Kharoti make sure you put it in "architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {}

Comment: @BasheerKharoti it should go away after npm install

Comment: Whitelist CommonJS dependency for lodash and moment works for me. sample: `"allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["lodash", "moment"],`

Comment: I get this for 'moment.js'. What is his ES version which I can install in Angular project?