# Angular 10: CommonJs and AMD Dependencies can cause optimization bailouts, hotkeys.js depends on 'mousetrap'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

We are receiving this build warning in Angular 10. How can this be fixed? Is there an alternative NPM like Lodash-es ?

> hotkeys.js depends on 'mousetrap'. CommonJs and AMD Dependencies can cause optimization bailouts

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ8J6.png)

Resource: [Upgrading to Angular 10 - Fix CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592903/upgrading-to-angular-10-fix-commonjs-or-amd-dependencies-can-cause-optimizatio)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be fixed by you, if you prefer to contribute to the `hotkeys` module, by making it [ECMAScript compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Or you can just add the module to `allowedCommonJsDependencies` in your `angular.json` file as it shown on [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies).

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
     "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
        "lodash"
     ]
     ...
   }
   ...
},
```

And finally, you could just ignore the warning until someone makes the module ECMAScript compatible, or use another module with the same functionalities you're looking for.

Comment: Not everyone here asking questions is able to contribute to a production library. Maybe if we ask them kindly and teaching, someday they will.

Comment: Adding that configuration does not solve the problem and the warning continues to appear, and yes, that "solution" is in the official documentation, but IT DOES NOT WORK, it would be very good if the Angular team provided a solution that works for this problem