# How to replace CommonJS with EcmaScript for "@types/uuid"

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, commonjs

In my angular project, I am using   this library "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0", and I am getting a warning that says Warning:

../name.component.ts depends on 'uuid'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

I read about the problem and I understood that I should not use CommonJS as it increases the bundle size but instead I should use ecmascript. I wanted to replace it now but I could not find any replacment. Does anyone have a solution for this problem ?

BTW, I have seen this question ([Upgrading to Angular 10 - Fix CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592903/upgrading-to-angular-10-fix-commonjs-or-amd-dependencies-can-cause-optimizatio)) but it is specific to rxjs. I would like to know the solution in general or at least for the uuid library

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading to Angular 10 - Fix CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592903/upgrading-to-angular-10-fix-commonjs-or-amd-dependencies-can-cause-optimizatio/62604034#62604034)

Comment: The solution there is specific to rxjs, I would like the solution for the library in the question @R.Richards

Comment: Replace `rxjs-compat` with `@types/uuid` in the answer. Done.

Comment: Where exactly do you meen?

Comment: In your angular.json. See this: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Comment: That is simply ignoring the error. I want a solution for the warning not ignoring it.

Comment: That sounds like a question for library/module recommendation. That's off topic. Your problem is a CommonJS module and the solution is to replace it with a different module.

Comment: Well, I am asking about a solution which could be a recommendation!! You say the solution is to replace it with a different module.  I am asking about that different module.