# How do I make Angular happy with my npm packages I author? No "CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts"

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

First of all, I'm NOT talking about `"allowedCommonJsDependencies"`. That's just a matter of suppressing warnings. What I want to do is author an npm package, to be used by Angular projects as well as non-Angular projects, so that there will be no warnings which have to be suppressed.

My package already contains ESM-style modules, *as well as* CommonJS (and even minified UMD). There are both ES6 (ES2015) and ES5 code versions available. Here's the start of my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "@tubular/util",
  "version": "3.3.0",
  "description": "Miscellaneous utility functions",
  "browser-es5": "dist/web5/index.js",
  "browser-es6": "dist/web/index.js",
  "main": "dist/es5/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "es2015": "dist/es6/index.js",
  "esm2015": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index",
  "sideEffects": false,
```

The code at `dist/index.js` looks like this:

```js
export * from './browser-graphics-util';
export * from './browser-util';
export * from './misc-util';
export * from './string-util';
```

...and all the code that is exported above is written in the ESM style, using `import`, not `require`.

So why is Angular complaining about the CommonJS code, instead of happily grabbing the ESM code and using that instead, without any need for warnings?

Full source code here: https://github.com/kshetline/tubular_util

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592903/upgrading-to-angular-10-fix-commonjs-or-amd-dependencies-can-cause-optimizatio

Comment: @Piyush Jain, sorry, what you linked to is about *using* npm modules, as they are, that are CommonJS, not about *creating those npm modules* so that they can be consumed as ESM packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not incredibly well documented, but after I posted an issue on Github, I finally learned how Angular determines which code inside an npm package to use. Angular checks this hierarchy:

- es2015
- browser
- module
- main

The 'esm2015' property isn't even checked, and that's exactly where I'd put ESM-style code. I wrongly expected that 'es2015', without the 'm', shouldn't be ESM code.

Wrong!

My new package.json looks like this, with all of the code directories as they were before:

```
{
  "name": "@tubular/util",
  "version": "3.3.1",
  "description": "Miscellaneous utility functions",
  "browser": "dist/web/index.js",
  "browser-es5": "dist/web5/index.js",
  "main": "dist/es6/index.js",
  "main-es5": "dist/es5/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "es2015": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index",
  "sideEffects": false,
```

With this, Angular can optimize and tree-shake to its heart's content.