# Angular 13 Upgrade: CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts

Tags: angular, rxjs, commonjs

I'm getting a number of such warnings on various files while upgrading project from angular 12 to angular 13 (originally written in Angular 6).

'..ts' depends on 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

'..ts' depends on 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

'..ts' depends on 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

'..ts' depends on 'rxjs/Observable'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

'..ts' depends on 'rxjs/operators/map'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

'..ts' depends on 'rxjs/operators/tap'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

The link provided says here CommonJS is making your bundles larger, but I'm not clear what change should I make to my code. Please advise!
For example, I have:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators/tap';
import { catchError, retry, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

In my package.json I have

"rxjs": "^6.5.3",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",

and I'm using

"typescript": "~4.6.2"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading to Angular 10 - Fix CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592903/upgrading-to-angular-10-fix-commonjs-or-amd-dependencies-can-cause-optimizatio)

Comment: Thanks, I had added               "rxjs/BehaviorSubject",
              "rxjs/add/observable/throw",
              "rxjs/add/operator/catch",
              "rxjs/Observable",
              "rxjs/operators/map",
              "rxjs/operators/tap"  but adding "rxjs-compat" did the trick